# How to get tables <td> content by <th> value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have table with many rows in html like this .

```
<table id="selectTerminals" size="35">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Configure</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
        <tr dir-paginate="item in serverData1 | filter:filterData | itemsPerPage: serverData1.length">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.abvrName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td><p><input class="deleteFromList" name="delete" value="Delete " type="submit" ng-click="deleteFromList()"/></p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and on click delete button i want to take choosen items ID in deleteFromList() function and i need help cause i dont know how can i do it.

Comment: You should probably add the angular tag to this as well - if you are using it (I think you are because of the ng-click)

Comment: you can directly pass the id into deleteFromList.  ng-click="deleteFromList( item.id)"

Comment: @Shiladitya thank you man very much it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table id="selectTerminals" size="35">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Configure</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr dir-paginate="item in serverData1 | filter:filterData | itemsPerPage: serverData1.length">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.abvrName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>>
            <!-- Pass `this` to the deleteFromList -->
            <td><p><input class="deleteFromList" name="delete" value="Delete " type="submit" ng-click="deleteFromList(this)"/></p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

/* Assuming your function like this. */
function deleteFromList(ele)
{
    /* You could get the specified id by this. */
    var id = ele.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
    // other logic.
}
</script>
```

You can do like above.

Comment: i have error like this "Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined"

Comment: Are you sure that you have pass the parameter of `this`? Just like this `deleteFromList(this)`. @GiorgiGoginashvili

Answer (score 0):

I think your html template sould look like this:

```
<table id="selectTerminals" size="35">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Configure</th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>
    <tr dir-paginate="item in serverData1 | filter:filterData | itemsPerPage: serverData1.length">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.abvrName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td><p><input class="deleteFromList" name="delete" value="Delete " type="button" ng-click="deleteFromList(item)"/></p></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And then in your controller you do something like this:

```
$scope.deleteFromList = function(item) {
    var index = $scope.serverData1.indexOf(item);
    $scope.serverData1 = $scope.serverData1.slice(index, 1);
}
```